# How to extract data from a website that requires login + OTP

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to download recommended jobs/resumes from a popular recruitment portal www.naukri.com..
The challenge is it first asks for login.. and then it asks for an OTP

How can I accomplish this using Python

**Update**
I have written a simple post request and below is my response

`import requests
page = requests.post("https://login.recruit.naukri.com/Login/loginService"  , data= {'username': ****, 'password': ****)
print(page.content, page.status_code)`

it is throwing an error, with the following message,

`{"status":false,"errorMsg":"There is some error right now. Please refresh and try again.In case the error persists, contact support@naukri.com along with your username."} 200`

However, PFA the screenshot when logging in via Web.. it works perfectly fine

[image]

Comment: you can do it with flak 2 different API one for login if it gives success response then the second OTP  verify  API and if success then do your scraping

Comment: What's your OPT mechanism? If it's google authentication then you can simple use the library to get the OPT code ( I can share the code).

Comment: @supputuri, the OTP mechanisam is via phone number.. it actually opens a new pop up windown ans asks to enter OTP..

Comment: @ManaliKagathara are you referring to flask instead of flak?
I would like to know best way to automate the entire process

Comment: yes, sorry my typing mistake, you can do it with the help of flask API.there is a step for otp verify and it will be input from user so, the first API for login and give response accordingly. if success response the execute another OTP verify API for the same selenium browser.